# Where do I type in the password in the Realm Browser mac app?

Tags: android, macos, mobile, encryption, realm

I get this screenshot, and when I press "enter encryption key" Realm Browser opens up a blank database with no prompt or anything

[image: Manually Enter Password]

I do have encryption enabled on my realm database.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Realm did you used to create the database? Was it the new version 0.96? This version brings a [breaking file format change](https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-0.96.0/), which is not supported yet by the AppStore version of the browser.

There is a [prerelease version of the browser](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/0.96-prerelease), which supports the new file format.

Encryption in Realm happens at first place and doesn't give any indication whether the Realm file is valid or not for security reasons. So the browser can't differentiate between that and this error message from the screenshot may appear in cases like yours a little confusing / misleading.

Comment: I'm on android, so it's `0.83.1`.  Trying that prelease version, I still get the same issue.

Comment: Hi Boomesh! I'm the maintainer of the Realm Browser. I just tried it myself and confirmed that something had gone wrong in the project that was preventing the dialog window from appearing. I just fixed it and re-uploaded it to the prerelease page. Please download it and try again!