# Realm Browser not allowing me to open files

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I've updated Realm Browser this morning to version 0.95.2, using the previous version I had no issues opening and viewing realm files but it seems now that I'm unable to do this and when I want to open this file this is the message that I'm getting.

[image]

I have no idea as to why I'm getting the since I have no encryption set and the file type has the extension .realm at the end has anyone else had or got this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33180533/5257295). Quoting:

> Version 0.96 of Realm brings a [breaking file format change](https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-0.96.0/), which is not supported yet by the AppStore version of the browser.
>
> There is a [prerelease version of the browser](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/0.96-prerelease), which supports the new file format.

Due to this realm database file format change you may get the encryption error. As the browser fails to read your realm file it can't tell whether it's encrypted or corrupted.